# What pickup time signature is this

Tags: sheet-music, rhythm, time-signatures, meter

How can you have an eighth note quadruplet and three eighth notes after. And how can you have a quadruplet with a dotted half note and two quarter notes?[image]

[image: measure with eighth note quadruplet in RH and quarter note quadruplet in LH]

Comment: Some additional context would be very helpful here. Title? Composer? Measure(s) before and after?

Comment: What is the beat listed at the start of this piece?  What do other measures look like?

Answer (score 3):

The underlying beat is most likely a beat of 3/8 base. If the excerpt makes up a whole measure I propose that would be 6/8:

Based on the head alignment and the beaming it looks to me like the last three right hand notes and the last two left hand notes should align, such as if they were written as a duplet under three eights. The quadruplet eighth notes in the right hand look like they should take the same time as the three eighths after. The quadruplet 4ths in the left hand I suppose read as "4 quarters in place of three", which divides the two dotted quarter beats into 4 beats. Personally I’d notate this like this (if my reading is correct):

[image]

or like this

[image]

or in a 4 base time signature like this

[image]

Comment: I like your answer better.

Comment: @Aaron As you’ve deleted your answer I’ve removed any now broken references to it. I think we can safely say that the person engraving this did not spend a lot of time thinking about clarity ...

Comment: The second image looks like a drum part to me. The A-E-A-E then would be kick-snare-kick-snare. Not something you would play with the left hand on a piano.